# How exactly does pointer value incrementing work?

Tags: c, loops, c-strings, function-definition, strcat

so I was working on creating the raw function of concatenating a string in c. One solution that was provided to me was :

```
char *_strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
    int c, c2;

    c = 0;

    while (dest[c])
        c++;

    for (c2 = 0; src[c2] ; c2++)
        dest[c++] = src[c2];

    return (dest);
}
```

The part that confuses me is `while (dest[c])`, and other similar parts. I've already gone through pointers through various resources but I can't seem to understand this part. A good explanation will be much appreciated.

Comment: The loops in the code do 2 things: the while loop finds the end of the destination string and the for loop concatenates the source characters to the destination string.

Comment: In `while(COND)`, what type does the condition `COND` have to be? What type is `dest[c]`? What kind of conversion do you think could exist from one  to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the function is incorrect. It does not build a concatenated string because it does not append the terminating zero character `'\0'` to the result (`dest`) string in this for loop

```
for (c2 = 0; src[c2] ; c2++)
    dest[c++] = src[c2];
```

Also the function should be declared like

```
char * _strcat( char *dest, const char *src );
```

because the appended string (`src`) is not changed.

This while loop

```
while (dest[c])
    c++;
```

is equivalent to

```
while (dest[c] != '\0' )
    c++;
```

and this for loop

```
for (c2 = 0; src[c2] ; c2++)
    dest[c++] = src[c2];
```

is equivalent to

```
for (c2 = 0; src[c2] != '\0' ; c2++)
    dest[c++] = src[c2];
```

That is the loops continue their iterations until the terminating zero character '\0' is encountered in the while loop in the string `dest` (to find its end) and in the second loop in the string `src` to find its end..

A non-zero scalar expression is evaluated as a logical true in conditions.

And the variables `c` and `c2` should have the unsigned type `size_t` instead of the type `int` because objects of the type `int` can be not large enough to store string lengths.

Also you should not define names starting from the underscore character.

As for your question

> How exactly does pointer value incrementing work?

then the pointers themselves are not incremented. There are used expressions with the subscript operator to access elements of strings as for example `dest[c]` or `dest[c++]` or `src[c2]`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
char * my_strcat( char *dest, const char *src )
{
    char *p = dest;

    while ( *p != '\0' ) ++p;

    while ( ( *p++ = *src++ ) != '\0' );

    return dest;
}
```

In the shown function there are indeed incremented pointers `p` and `src` and neither expression with the subscript operator is used..

Comment: Note: `while (dest[c])` works because `'\0'` is false.

Answer (score 1):

`char *dest` is an pointer to char and it's pointed to the first character by default. Then the following loop will move the pointer offset to the end of the string.

```
c = 0;

while (dest[c])
   c++;
```